# Clojure swap! atom executed in parallel

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, clojure

I'm playing with clojure to do a script to read as input a sequence of URIs from a file and do a report on the status code for them.

I've implemented this using `clojure.core.async/pipeline-async` to execute the HTTP call to the URI (using an httpkit async call).

I want to monitor the execution of the script so I've an atom for the state:

```clj
(let [processing (atom [(System/currentTimeMillis) 0])]
```

and a function to track the progress.

```clj
(defn track-progress [total progress]
  (swap! progress 
         (fn [[time count]]
            (let [incremented-count (inc count)
                  now (System/currentTimeMillis)]
              (if (= 0 (mod incremented-count (max 1 (int (/ total 20)))))
                (do
                  (println (str "Progress " incremented-count "/" total " | " (- now time) "ms"))
                  [now incremented-count])
                [time incremented-count])))))
```

Using it after the HTTP call:

```clj
(a/pipeline-async
      parallelism
      output-chan
      (fn [[an-id uri] result]
        (http/head uri {:throw-exceptions false
                        :timeout timeout}
                   (fn [{:keys [status error]}]
                     (track-progress total processing)
                     (a/go 
                        (if (nil? error)
                            (do (a/>! result [an-id (keyword (str status))])
                                (a/close! result))
                            (do (a/>! result [an-id :error])
                                (a/close! result)))))))
      input-chan)
```

The `processing` atom is created in a `let` expression, using that `pipeline-async` part.
Everything seems working fine, apart from that log.
I found out that sometimes the logging is very weird, having stuffs like this:

```
Progress 500/10000 | 11519ms
Progress 500/10000 | 11519msProgress 500/10000 | 11519ms

Progress 1000/10000 | 11446ms
Progress 1000/10000 | 11446ms
Progress 1500/10000 | 9503ms
Progress 2000/10000 | 7802ms
Progress 2500/10000 | 12822ms
Progress 2500/10000 | 12822msProgress 2500/10000 | 12822ms
Progress 2500/10000 | 12822ms

Progress 3000/10000 | 10623ms
Progress 3500/10000 | 9018ms
Progress 4000/10000 | 9618ms
Progress 4500/10000 | 13544ms
Progress 5000/10000 | 10541ms
Progress 5500/10000 | 10817ms
Progress 6000/10000 | 8921ms
Progress 6500/10000 | 9078ms
Progress 6500/10000 | 9078ms
Progress 7000/10000 | 9270ms
Progress 7500/10000 | 11826msProgress 7500/10000 | 11826msProgress 7500/10000 | 11826ms
```

The output is formatted as it is wrote in the shell, it seems that sometimes the same `println` is executed multiple times, or the `fn` passed to the `swap!` function is executed in parallel (no concurrency) in the atom.
(If the the `println` I remove the `str` to create the string to print, the lines in which I have the same progress multiple times are totally mixed up like `ProgressProgress 7500/10000 | 11826ms7500/100007500 | 11826msProgress/10000 | 11826ms`)

Is it something wrong with my code?
Or I am getting the `atom` wrong, as I supposed it not allows the parallel execution of a function changing its state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Clojure atom is designed specifically so that in a multi-threaded program, there can be multiple threads executing `swap!` on a single atom, and if your program does this, those update functions `f` given to `swap!` *can* run simultaneously.  The only part of `swap!` that is synchronized is a 'compare and swap' operation that effectively does:

- lock the atom's state
- check if its current value is `identical?` to the reference it contained before `f` began executing, and if it is, replace it with the new object returned by `f`.
- Unlock the atom's state".

The function `f` may take a long time to calculate a new value from the current one, but the critical section above is merely a pointer comparison, and if equal, a pointer assignment.

That is why the doc string for `swap!` says "Note that f may be called multiple times, and thus should be free of side effects."

Comment: If you change your function `track-progress` so that the function you pass to `swap!` only does calculation and return of a new vector, and then _after_ that you do an `if` statement to println what you want, conditionally, then you should never see multiple log lines with the same `increment-count` value.  You still might see multiple on the same line, because `println` is not atomic.

Comment: Got it, so I misunderstood the `swap!`, thank you for clarify how it works!

Comment: Or if you want to linearize everything, you could use an agent instead of an atom.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to serialize the output stream from a group of concurrently executing threads. You could use an agent to serialize access to a piece of mutable state, but here you have a degenerate case without state, only with side-effects.  For this case, [the `locking` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/locking) is all you need.

An example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn do-println
  [& args]
  (apply println args))

(def lock-obj (Object.))
(defn do-println-locking
  [& args]
  (locking lock-obj
    (apply println args)))

(def sleep-millis 500)
(defn wait-and-print
  [print-fn id]
  (Thread/sleep sleep-millis)
  (print-fn (format "wait-and-print %s is complete" id)))

(defn start-threads
  [print-fn count]
  (println "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  (let [futures (forv [i (range count)]
                  (future (wait-and-print print-fn i)))]
    (doseq [future futures]
      ; block until future is complete
      (deref future))))

(dotest
  (start-threads do-println 10)
  (start-threads do-println-locking 10))
```

Typical result:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
wait-and-print 4 is completewait-and-print 3 is completewait-and-print 2 is complete
wait-and-print 8 is completewait-and-print 9 is complete
wait-and-print 6 is completewait-and-print 1 is complete

wait-and-print 7 is complete
wait-and-print 0 is complete

wait-and-print 5 is complete


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
wait-and-print 5 is complete
wait-and-print 8 is complete
wait-and-print 7 is complete
wait-and-print 9 is complete
wait-and-print 6 is complete
wait-and-print 3 is complete
wait-and-print 0 is complete
wait-and-print 4 is complete
wait-and-print 2 is complete
wait-and-print 1 is complete
```

So you can see the output without serialization from `locking` is jumbled, while each `println` in the 2nd case is allowed to complete one-at-a-time (even though the order is still random).

If `println` printed one char at a time instead of one string at a time, the results in the unsynchronized case would be even more jumbled.  Modify the output functions to print each character separately:

```
(defn do-println
  [& args]
  (doseq [ch (str/join args)]
    (print ch))
  (newline))

(def lock-obj (Object.))
(defn do-println-locking
  [& args]
  (locking lock-obj
    (apply do-println args)))
```

with typical result:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
wwwwwaaawwiiiattti--taaa--nnaiddnaa--dwpp-irrptaiir-niiantnttn  -dw2ta-  ani96ipds trn- i-pcndrota-impn nrpd4itl- n eipt5tr s e7i 
 incisots   mc0cpo olmmieppstll ee
etctteo
e-
 amnidps-l pectroeai
intt- a1n di-sip rcsio nmctmpo plm3lew etaiei
spt t-lceeatone
d
m-pplreitnet
 8 is complete
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
wait-and-print 3 is complete
wait-and-print 9 is complete
wait-and-print 8 is complete
wait-and-print 4 is complete
wait-and-print 6 is complete
wait-and-print 7 is complete
wait-and-print 0 is complete
wait-and-print 1 is complete
wait-and-print 5 is complete
wait-and-print 2 is complete
```

but we see that `locking` serializes the function calls so that the active call must complete before the next can begin.